# My Tiny Death Star froze, restarted the PC and now its progress is gone

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm playing Tiny Death Star on Windows 8.1. I'm 25 over levels at the moment. Today the game crashed and I had to hard-reboot the computer (keep the power button pressed). When I returned to the game, it's back to the beginning of the game, with The Emperor giving me a tutorial. Any way I could save back my progress?

Comment: No chance you had a backup before the crash?  It's been a while since I used Windows, but do they have a Time Machine function like MacOS does?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I believe I did a similar method for my older Windows, but I'm still new to Windows 8. I guess that's the only way, thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened to me on Android when my phone ran out of power, and unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to restore it. Somehow, it also corrupted my save in such a way that it generated a strange, new 30-story Death Star a few days later though, so hopefully at least that happens for you too.

Comment: Wow, maybe that might happen, I'll keep my fingers crossed. Thanks for the help by the way.